# ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] when trying to upload csv file to google analytics

Tags: python-3.x, google-api

Using the snippet [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/uploads/uploadData#examples) (where I have created a `service` module) I get an `ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054]` when I try to upload a CSV-file to Google Analytics.

I am perfectly capble of getting the lists of already uploaded files and delete them (using the same `service` module) but uploading throws the error.

My code, python 3.7.9, is below (`...` is of course not the correct credentials)

```py
    try:
        media = MediaFileUpload('test.csv',
                                mimetype='application/octet-stream',
                                resumable=False)

        daily_upload = service.management().uploads().uploadData(
            accountId=...,
            webPropertyId=...,
            customDataSourceId=...,
            media_body=media).execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have problem with uploading data to GA. Do everything like in documentation but get: HttpError 404 when requesting ... returned "Not Found"
Getting lists works well but uploading fails.